# ZK MVVM Validation message automatic binding?

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I've got a Macrocomponent that combines a label, a textbox and an error label...

```
<mycomponent id="productname" caption="Product name" value="Apple XYZ" error=""/>
```

...and now I want to use that for binding...

Obviously I could write...

```
<mycomponent id="productname" caption="Product name" value="@bind(vm.productName)" error="@bind(vmsgs['productname'])"/>
```

(given, of course, a `validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')` somewhere above - the correct annotations are in place, so this binding works fine)

...but of course, I would have to do this for each field and it would clutter my .zul files. So, is there any chance to somehow, perhaps even in java code, to tell the component to bind itself to vmsgs with the components id, without having to give that for every field? So that this would have the same effect...

```
<mycomponent id="productname" caption="Product name" value="@bind(vm.productName)"/>
```

..or perhaps

```
<mycomponent id="productname" caption="Product name" value="@bind(vm.productName)" bindError="true"/>
```

Of course, the component should stay usable in a non-MVVM environment, so adding fixed bindings is probably out. Any chance, for example, to find out in Java if we are bound somehow and add our own binding automatically?

Comment: Could you post java validation part, please? My idea is to get the id of component from ValidationContex.getBindContext().getComponent() and manage the error by component id. Of sure, it works only if every component has a setted id.

Comment: The macrocomponent that has the error as an attribute has an id, no problem there. The sub-compnent also has, but of course, always the same. The validation part is, as of yet, nothing special, just some simple AbstractValidators checking and adding messages.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem was actually quite simple:

```
@ComponentAnnotation("@bind(vmsgs[self.id])")
public void setError(String value) {
    this.error.setValue(value);
}
```

This allows binding the error field to vmsgs[self.id], which in the case described above would bei vmsgs['productname'], which works.

It only starts getting complicated when I stack multiple of these components into another macrocomponent...

```
<zk>
     <mycomponent id="productname" caption="Product name" value="@bind(vm.productName)"
     <mycomponent id="producttype" caption="Product type" value="@bind(vm.productTye)"
</zk>
```

...because then, the originating component is no longer the mycomponent, but the "outer" macrocomponent, so that self.id (productname, producttype) will not be enough. This can be handled by giving the explicit key in the validator...

```
SavePropertyBinding binding = (SavePropertyBinding)ctx.getBindContext().getBinding();
String fieldName = binding.getFieldName();
```

...but then we have the problem, that the validator will not work with standalone mycomponents (who still expect the id as validator message key).

Well, it's a start and by using a custom annotation I taught my validators to recognize which id to use, perhaps not the best solution, but at least a solution.